# A multi-threaded python program never exit

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I tried to run below multi-threaded python program using python 3.4.3 interpreter. 
My expectation is that after all items in  dish_queue are gotten and processed (that's the purpose of function task_done, right?), the dish_queue will not block the program any more , so the program can exit normally.

The result is after the line `Drying desert <Thread(Thread-2, started 140245865154304)>` is printed out, the program never exits regardless of if the line `dish_queue.join()` is commented or not.
It seems the main thread is stuck in the statement `washer(dishes,dish_queue)` ? Can anybody explain to me why?

```
$ cat threading_dish.py     
import threading,queue
import time

def washer(dishes,dishqueue):
  for dish in dishes:
    time.sleep(5)
    print("washing",dish,threading.current_thread())
    time.sleep(5)
    dishqueue.put(dish)


def dryer(dishqueue):
  while True:
    dish=dishqueue.get()
    print("Drying",dish,threading.current_thread())
    #time.sleep(10)
    dishqueue.task_done()

dish_queue=queue.Queue()
for n in range(2):
    dryer_thread=threading.Thread(target=dryer,args=(dish_queue,))
    dryer_thread.start()

dishes=['salad','bread','entree','desert']
washer(dishes,dish_queue)
#dish_queue.join()

$ python3 threading_dish.py
washing salad <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140245895784256)>
Drying salad <Thread(Thread-1, started 140245873547008)>
washing bread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140245895784256)>
Drying bread <Thread(Thread-2, started 140245865154304)>
washing entree <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140245895784256)>
Drying entree <Thread(Thread-1, started 140245873547008)>
washing desert <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140245895784256)>
Drying desert <Thread(Thread-2, started 140245865154304)>
```

By comparison, if i run the multi-processing counterpart of the program, the program can exit normally after the last printout.
IS there any difference between the multi-threaded one and the multi-processing one that result in the opposite running result?

```
$ cat multiprocessing_dishes.py 
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
def washer(dishes,output):
  for dish in dishes:
    print('washing', dish, 'dish',mp.current_process())
    output.put(dish)

def dryer(input):
  while True:
    dish=input.get()
    print('Drying',dish,'dish',mp.current_process())
    time.sleep(5) 
    input.task_done()

dishqueue=mp.JoinableQueue()

dryerproc=mp.Process(target=dryer,args=(dishqueue,))
dryerproc.daemon=True
dryerproc.start()

dishes=['xxx','asa','aass']
washer(dishes,dishqueue)


dishqueue.join()

$ python3 multiprocessing_dishes.py 
washing xxx dish <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
washing asa dish <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
washing aass dish <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
Drying xxx dish <Process(Process-1, started daemon)>
Drying asa dish <Process(Process-1, started daemon)>
Drying aass dish <Process(Process-1, started daemon)>
$
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/queue.html

Queue.get() blocks, so after the queue is no longer being produced into, your dryer threads will block indefinitely.
You need to signal in some way to the dryer threads that the washing process is finished.

You can achieve this by querying a shared variable in the while loop's condition, or alternatively by enqueuing a poison pill for each thread. A poison pill is a pre-determined value, that lets a consuming thread know that it needs to terminate.

Comment: I appended the multi-processing counterpart of the program, and the JoinableQueue.get() didn't block. Why is there such difference?

Comment: In the second example the dryer thread is a daemon thread. Daemon threads are threads that do not prevent termination. In other words, if all of an application's runnable and blocked threads are daemon threads, then the application will terminate. The dryer threads **do** block on Queue.get(), they just don't prevent the process from terminating, and as soon as the main thread finishes its execution the process terminates. I would say that this is generally a bad solution, since if the main thread (or another non-daemon thread) had more work to do, then the daemon threads would remain blocked.